# enable ZTS on MAMP 3.0.2

Tags: php, compilation, pthreads, mamp

I am trying to install pthreads using the following command:

`sudo pecl install pthreads`

However, when doing so, I receive the following error message:

`checking checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
ERROR: /private/tmp/pear/install/pthreads/configure' failed`

Does anyone know how I can re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled?  I am using MAMP 3.0.2, and I thought that running `phpize` would recompile php, but when doing so I get this error:

`Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module`

Comment: do you resolve this issue, if yes - how?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enable ZTS post-build, you must install a thread safe version.

`phpize` is a tool for generating autoconf foo for extensions.